# Is it safe to locate a UPS close to server

Tags: ups, electrical-power

I have an Eaton 5S and a HP Microserver. I'm wondering if there's likely to be any problems stacking the former on of the latter (aside from stability). Do I need to be aware of any electrical interference in the way that UPSes work?

Comment: Just make sure you provide plenty of ventilation. We have battery back ups at every desk and several in our server racks. Just don't let them get hot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to be aware of electrical interference, but you do need to make sure they are adequately ventilated.   Look at the user manual - it will often / usually provide minimum requirements for airflow arround the UPS.

I would point out that any interference is more likely to come in from them being on a common phase / circuit - although this is not likely to be a big issue unless the UPS's are very large and/or very differently specced.

Comment: The UPS is powering the server. I'd hope they're on a common phase / circuit ;)

Comment: Sorry,I thought you were talking about stacking UPSs  (I think you might have modified the question also !)

Answer (score 7):

Rack mount UPS units are meant to be in the same rack as the equipment they're protecting. That's why they're rack mounted. People don't purchase/rent separate racks for their UPS units.

A UPS is typically placed in the bottom of the rack so as to not skew the center of gravity of the rack because UPS units tend to be heavier than the other equipment in the rack. It's not considered best practice to place your UPS unit above the other equipment in the rack.

Comment: Actually, its not at all uncommon for a UPS to take up a whole rack (or more) by themselves - It depends on the amount of power required.  There are certainly advantages to UPS's in the same cabinet as other gear, but the reason they are (sometimes ) rack mountable is it's a convenient modular format suitable for data centers.  See http://fsp-ups.com/mplusop.htm for an example.